# Converting a list of latitude and longitude into city names output should be .xls

Tags: excel, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have an Excel sheet that has a list of latitude and longitude as below:

```
County     latdecdeg londecdeg     State
Allegheny   40.5254 -80.07213889    PA
Allegheny   40.5526 -80.1159        PA
Allegheny   40.5191 -80.13090556    PA
Allegheny   40.5134 -80.13508889    PA
Allegheny   40.5228 -80.17644722    PA
Allegheny   40.496  -79.939375      PA
Allegheny   40.6154 -79.7586        PA
Allegheny   40.2733 -80.10555556    PA
Armstrong   40.7559 -79.6435        PA
Armstrong   40.815  -79.535025      PA
Armstrong   40.8052 -79.51341389    PA
Beaver      40.6957 -80.36681667    PA
Berks       40.2485 -76.03885833    PA
Berks       40.2979 -75.89966111    PA
Blair       40.5622 -78.32684722    PA
Blair       40.6001 -78.31262222    PA
```

I need to populate the corresponding city names.
How do i do it?

Comment: Downvote because, as Mano Marks mentioned, this violates the Terms of Service

Answer (score 1):

From within Excel you will need to create a plugin or possibly a macro (I am not familiar with how much power you have from macros) to do it for you. The process is called "Reverse Geocoding" and you can use the Google Maps API for it.

See this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: I am pretty new to all these.I do not know how to write micro for this neither ReverseGeocodeing.

Comment: This would likely violate the terms of service of the Google Maps API since it requires you use the geocoding with a Google Map. You should check the terms to see if your usage complies:
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms